# Parsing a text in a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to parse the string "External-dep" in the variable "output" and create a list of dictionary with its values,this variable is present at multiple places in the variable "output"..need to get the latest one..values to "External-dep" are always integers.. am currently stuck at below i cant parse the string "External-dep",can anyone provide inputs?

```
Master_change ="12345"
external_dep ={}
output="""change Ied13af85dec9128b6a715739b50ae2f33a92cf14
  project: platform/data
  branch: master
  id: Ied13af85dec9128b6a715739b50ae2f33a92cf14
  number: 12345
  subject: code: test
  owner:
    name: danile david
    email: gdavid@com.domain.com
    username: gdavid
  url: https://review-android.company.com/12345
  createdOn: 2013-02-19 18:10:36 PST
  lastUpdated: 2013-04-24 13:43:23 PDT
  sortKey: 0024a01b0003dc6c
  open: true
  status: NEW
  comments:
    timestamp: 2013-04-22 15:20:17 PDT
    reviewer:
      name: danile david
      email: gdavid@com.domain.com
      username: gdavid
    message: Patch Set 4:

             External-dep: 311957
  comments:
    timestamp: 2013-04-24 13:43:23 PDT
    reviewer:
      name: danile david
      email: gdavid@com.domain.com
      username: gdavid
    message: Patch Set 4:

             External-dep: 312994 311957 312591

type: stats
rowCount: 1
runTimeMilliseconds: 4"""

    for line in output :
        if 'External-dep' in line:#make External-dep case-insensitive
            print line

    '''
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
    external_dep = {
        '12345': ['312994','311957','312591']
        }

'''
```

Comment: use `for line in output.splitlines():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would give you the output you are looking for (assuming order doesn't matter, although correct me if it does). I use the same output string you mention above but do not list it here to preserve space.

```
>>> import re
>>> external_dep = dict()
>>> deps = ' '.join(re.findall(r'(?<=External-dep:\s)[\d ]+(?=\n)', output)).split()
>>> deps
['311957', '312994', '311957', '312591']
>>> external_dep[Master_change] = list(set(deps))
>>> external_dep
{'12345': ['311957', '312994', '312591']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a hurry, use this, but otherwise use something better:

```
for line in output.splitlines() :
    if 'external-dep' in line.lower():
        print line
        external_dep[Master_change] = list(line.replace("External-dep: ", "").strip().split(' '))

print external_dep
```

Outputs:

```
{'12345': ['312994', '311957', '312591']}
```